# Why does this snippet fail to produce false sharing effects?

Tags: c++, false-sharing

I tried to make a small snippet that reproduces a false sharing scenario. This is what I came up with:

```
#include <thread>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

const size_t s_nNumberOfThreads = 16;

volatile __declspec(align(64)) int s_pValues[s_nNumberOfThreads];

void IncrementValue(size_t nValueIndex)
{
    int nValue = 0;
    s_pValues[nValueIndex] = nValue;
    while (true)
    {
        if (s_pValues[nValueIndex] != nValue)
        {
            break;
        }
        nValue++;
        s_pValues[nValueIndex] = nValue;
    }
    // We messed up the memory
    int i = 3; // Breakpoint here
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::vector<std::thread> Threads;
    size_t nThreadIndex = 0;
    while (nThreadIndex < s_nNumberOfThreads)
    {
        Threads.push_back(std::thread(IncrementValue, nThreadIndex++));
    }
    for(auto &Thread : Threads)
    {
        Thread.join();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

However running this under VS2013 in debug build (so no optimizations), fails to produce any errors - the break-point is not hit and the threads do not exit. Is my example inaccurate or is there something that prevents this from exposing false sharing on a single physical CPU?

Comment: False sharing degrades performance. It doesn't trample over adjacent memory locations.

Comment: I`m not an expert on it, but I would add a thread sleep call in the end of the while loop - my guess you are testing the value too close to when you set it.

Comment: @T.C. - I may have misunderstood something but shouldn't I at least once get a corrupted read resulting from the fact that another thread wrote to the cache line between the read and write?

Comment: No, on an x86 the caches will be synchronized by the hardware. It might take extra time, but doesn't produce incorrect values.

Comment: @BoPersson thanks for the explaination. I found this (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5270/aewcy/index.html) that also states that the lines are invalided at hardware level. Did not know that:)

Comment: Hardware details are interesting but not really relevant. The C++ memory model guarantees that reads/writes to different memory locations do not conflict, and so it must work in any conforming implementation. If there's some crazy hardware that doesn't have native support for this, the implementation must do whatever it takes to ensure that it works regardless.

Comment: @T.C sorry for the additional questions - but isn't C++11 the first standard that introduced a standardized memory model?